# BottomNavigationView - How to avoid recreation of Fragments and reuse them

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I would like to make a bottom navigation bar in my project. Every view has it's own fragment. The problem is that every time i click on the button to change the view for example from recents to favorites it creates new fragment with completely new states(e.g. scroll position, text changed whatever my fragment contains). I know that in official Android  documentation there was written that bottom navigation bar should reset the task states, but i think it is too uncomfortable for users.
I would like to have kind of similar functionality like instagram that you change from feed to explore and back to feed the scroll position the image caches everything remains saved. I tried almost every way to solve this problem the only thing that worked is by setting visibility GONE and setting visibility VISIBLE according to situation but i understand that it is not RIGHT way there should be better way of doing this and i am not talking about manually saving needed instances. I followed almost every tutorial about bottom nav fragments but the interesting thing is that no one is interested to make it use without calling new every time.

[image]

[image]

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, FirstFragment.newInstance());
fragmentTransaction.commit();

bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_dialer:
                fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_email:
                fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_map:
                fragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I also tried the onAttach and Deattach solutions but again no success.

[VIDEO LINK : new i tried Nino Handler version it only works when i tap on the same fragment button](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Z9TaFoSS7hYVE1OTJtTlA2ajA)

**Maybe it is connected that i am using canary version or something wrong in my gradle dependencies?**
[image]

[image: NEW UPDATES:]

NEW UPDATES:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;


    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE = "fragment_one";
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO = "fragment_two";

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment currentFragment;

    String TAG = "babken";
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                   fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = FragmentFirst.newInstance();
                    }
                    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);

                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                     fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = FragmentSecond.newInstance();
                    }
                    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO);

                    break;
            }
            return true;

        }
    };

    private void replaceFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @NonNull String tag) {
        if (!fragment.equals(currentFragment)) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.armen, fragment, tag)
                    .commit();
            currentFragment = fragment;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = FragmentFirst.newInstance();
        }
        replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had similar issue, but this code solved my problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new DashboardFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new NotificationsFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = null;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    setFragment(fragment2, "2", 1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    setFragment(fragment3, "3", 2);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, int position) {
        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment).commit();
        } else if (active != null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).add(R.id.main_container, fragment, tag).commit();
        } else {
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
        }
        navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
        active = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (active == fragment1) {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably making a little mistake...this point if the code is to avoid recreation of new instances.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thankful

Comment: hide & show called any lifecycle method or not.? how can I animate recycler view when showing fragment any idea .

Comment: @Bukunmi hide and show not working. Any idea? When I click on the tabs, it's just showing the first tab only. Please help.

Comment: This answer is ***WRONG***. You cannot assume to create a new instance of a Fragment without first trying to get it with `findFragmentByTag`. This will break after process death.

Comment: This is a quick fix, if you have a more accurate solution, post it.

Comment: why are you not hiding lastActiveFragment when current Selected fragment is not added ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce please suggest best approach for this according to you, please!!!!

Comment: @RahulPawar if you don't want to recreate the Fragments as you navigate, you should add them first, get them with findFragmentByTag when savedInstanceState != null, and otherwise attach/detach (or show/hide) them as you navigate. I wrote a sample earlier which you can see here: https://github.com/Zhuinden/BottomNavChildFragmentExample/blob/40d7b87ee77e96eae2b559b3b727609fb015198e/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/bottomnavfragmentexample/RootFragment.kt#L16-L98

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't keep the fragment instances globally.
Instead add a tag to the fragment when creating them

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(), TAG_PLACEHOLDER)
            .commit();
```

Then you can always retrieve it like this:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_PLACEHOLDER);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment, TAG_PLACEHOLDER)
            .commit();
```

UPDATE: I updated my answer and to provide a complete solution:

```
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE = "fragment_one";
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO = "fragment_two";
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_THREE = "fragment_three";

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Fragment currentFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // instantiate the fragment manager
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
    }
    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_dialer:
                    // I'm aware that this code can be optimized by a method which accepts a class definition and returns the proper fragment
                    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
                    }
                    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_ONE);
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_email:
                    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
                    }
                    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_TWO);
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_map:
                    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_THREE);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance();
                    }
                    replaceFragment(fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_THREE);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void replaceFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @NonNull String tag) {
    if (!fragment.equals(currentFragment)) {
        fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, tag)
            .commit();
        currentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

ADDITIONAL INFO: If you want to be sure that the fragment states don't change and if you also want to be able to swipe the fragments you should consider using a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) and change the current fragment in the adapter with every click event

Comment: i tried it the link i put in the bottom of the question check it out

Comment: do you use 3 different tags?

Comment: How can i send you personal message to.show you my.code ?

Comment: I updated the question and it again gives the same output. 
i do not know what is the problem.
you are using this code and it keeps all fragments states ?
what is you android studio version ?
i do not think that it is problem but as you can see i am doing the same but it doesnt work for me

Comment: try to add setRetainInstance(true) in your fragments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149379/discussion-between-android-developer-and-nino-handler).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Kotlin Extension function for FragmentManager class

```
fun FragmentManager.switch(containerId: Int, newFrag: Fragment, tag: String) {

    var current = findFragmentByTag(tag)
    beginTransaction()
        .apply {

            //Hide the current fragment
            primaryNavigationFragment?.let { hide(it) }

            //Check if current fragment exists in fragmentManager
            if (current == null) {
                current = newFrag
                add(containerId, current!!, tag)
            } else {
                show(current!!)
            }
        }
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(current)
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

This can be called by `supportFragmentManager.swtich(R.id.container,newFrag,newFrag.TAG)` from `onNavigationItemSelected`

Answer (score 1):

So I have been researching for this for a long time and figured out that there is no way to reuse fragment with AUTOMATICALLY saved states you have to save your needed states manually then retrieve them whenever a new fragment is created but what about scroll position it is too hard and even in some cases it is impossible to save scroll view position state(e.g. recycler view). So i used the concept called VISIBILITY when i click on the button that fragment becomes visible others hide automatically.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem .. could you give me some details about the solution or some code ?

Comment: Is your issue on your own question working? I have the same problem. @ArmenHovhannisian

Comment: @ArmenHovhannisian `If someone need more detailed explanation about VISIBILITY.VISIBLE and VISIBILITY.GONE comment i will go through details` Can you please provide more detail?

Comment: This provided no actual code as reference. Should not be accepted answer

Comment: i think @Bukunmi answer's should be accepted not this.

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers are using `fragmentTransaction.replace(...)`. This will replace the current fragment by destroying it (which is causing the problem). Therefore all those solutions won't actually work.

This is the closest thing I could get to as a solution for this problem:

```
private void selectContentFragment(Fragment fragmentToSelect)
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (this.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().contains(fragmentToSelect)) {
        // Iterate through all cached fragments.
        for (Fragment cachedFragment : this.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if (cachedFragment != fragmentToSelect) {
                // Hide the fragments that are not the one being selected.
                fragmentTransaction.hide(cachedFragment);
            }
        }
        // Show the fragment that we want to be selected.
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentToSelect);
    } else {
        // The fragment to be selected does not (yet) exist in the fragment manager, add it.
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToSelect);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**To make this work, you should keep track of the fragments in an array (or in separate variables) in your Activity. I for reference pre-instantiated all fragments in a SparseArray.**

Comment: i tried this, it works but there was a  little issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attach() and detach() methods:

```
private FirstFragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
private SecondFragment secondFragment= SecondFragment.newInstance();
private ThirdFragment thirdFragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance();

navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_dialer:
                    changeFragment(firstFragment, "firstFragment");
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_email:
                    changeFragment(secondFragment, "secondFragment");
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_map:
                    changeFragment(thirdFragment, "thirdFragment");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, String tagFragmentName) {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    if (currentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    }

    Fragment fragmentTemp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tagFragmentName);
    if (fragmentTemp == null) {
        fragmentTemp = fragment;
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragmentTemp, tagFragmentName);
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.attach(fragmentTemp);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragmentTemp);
    fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    fragmentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that. 
You **declare the fragments** in the class.

```
Fragment firstFragment,secondFragment,thirdFragment;
```

then in the **switch-case** you can code as that:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_dialer:
        if(firstFragment != null) {
            fragment = firstFragment;
        }else{
            fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.menu_email:
        // the same ...
        break;
    case R.id.menu_map:
        //the same ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but let me check  a second time maybe i missed something.

Comment: every time it creates new fragment

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer nearly helped me but had an issue that whenever I open new fragments the very first time, they overlapped but doesn't get overlapped once I open them again by pressing the menu buttons.

So I modified his code and obtained the solution using the following code:

```
 private fun selectContentFragment(fragmentToSelect: Fragment) {
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        if (fragmentManager?.fragments?.contains(fragmentToSelect)!!) {
            // Show the fragment that we want to be selected.
            fragmentTransaction?.show(fragmentToSelect)
        } else {
            // The fragment to be selected does not (yet) exist in the fragment manager, add it.
            fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.container, fragmentToSelect)
        }
        // Iterate through all cached fragments.
        for (cachedFragment in fragmentManager?.fragments!!) {
            if (cachedFragment !== fragmentToSelect) {
                // Hide the fragments that are not the one being selected.
                // Uncomment following line and change the name of the fragment if your host isn't an activity and a fragment otherwise whole view will get hidden.
                // if (!cachedFragment.toString().contains("HomeContainerFragment"))

                fragmentTransaction?.hide(cachedFragment)
            }
        }
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()
    }
```

Make sure you're not passing the fragment's new instance every time.

**This will work:**

```
selectContentFragment(
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.home -> frag1
                        R.id.photoGallery -> frag2
                        else -> Home()
                    }
            )
```

where `frag1` and `frag2` are global variables defined as:

```
 val frag1 = Home()
 val frag2 = PhotoGallery()
```

**This will not work:**

```
selectContentFragment(
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.home -> Home()
                        R.id.photoGallery -> PhotoGallery()
                        else -> Home()
                    }
            )
```

It wasted my several hours. Hope it helps others!

Comment: How to handle backstack with this method?

Answer (score 0):

**This code very helpful for me. Just like youtube. **

```
private Deque<Integer> fragmentIds = new ArrayDeque<>(3);
int itemId;
private HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
private FavouriteFragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
private NearmeFragment nearmeFragment = new NearmeFragment();
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentIds.push(R.id.action_home);
    showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(homeFragment);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemClicked);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemClicked = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        itemId= item.getItemId();
        if(fragmentIds.contains(itemId)){
            fragmentIds.remove(itemId);
        }
        fragmentIds.push(itemId);
        showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
        return true;
    }
};

private Fragment getFragment(int fragmentId) {
    switch (fragmentId) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            return homeFragment;
        case R.id.action_favorites:
            return favouriteFragment;
        case R.id.action_nearme:
            return nearmeFragment;
    }
    return homeFragment;
}

private void showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(fragmentIds.getLast() != R.id.action_home){
            fragmentIds.addLast(R.id.action_home);
    }
    fragmentIds.pop();
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(fragmentIds.size()-1).setChecked(true);
    if (!fragmentIds.isEmpty()) {
        showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(fragmentIds.peek()));
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin user may help this code :

First create a FragmentManager extension class

```
fun FragmentManager.replace(containerId: Int, fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
var current = findFragmentByTag(tag)
beginTransaction()
    .apply {
        //Hide the current fragment
        primaryNavigationFragment?.let { hide(it) }

        //Check if current fragment exists in fragmentManager
        if (current == null) {
            current = fragment
            add(containerId, current!!, tag)
        } else {
            show(current!!)
        }
    }
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK)
    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(current)
    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
    .commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
```

}

Now simply call it on your

```
 onNavigationItemSelected



supportFragmentManager.replace(R.id.fragment_id,YourFragmentClass,yourFragment.TAG)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new DashboardFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new NotificationsFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = fragment1;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    setFragment(fragment2, "2", 1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    setFragment(fragment3, "3", 2);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, int position) {
        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment).commit();
        } else {
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment, tag).commit();
        }
        navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
        active = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (active == fragment1) {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setFragment(fragment1, "1", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Maintain Bottom sheet fragment `Reusable`
2. BackPress Maintain
3. double back press to exit

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Toaster toaster;
    private final Fragment androidFragment = new AndroidFragment();
    private final Fragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    Fragment active;    
    String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toaster = new Toaster(this);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    renderFragment(androidFragment, "android");
    active = androidFragment;
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            item -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + active );
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_android){
                    renderFragment(androidFragment, "android");
                    return true;
                }
                else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
                    renderFragment(settingsFragment, "settings");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
    );
}

private void renderFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fragment.isAdded()){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
    }
    else {
        if(active != null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment, tag)
                    .hide(active)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
        else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment, tag)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    }
    active = fragment;
}
}
```

This worked for me Guys.

Answer (score -1):

Create the three fragments as members of the class and reuse them.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Fragment mFirstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    private final Fragment mSecondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    private final Fragment mThirdFragment = new ThirdFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...... 
        ......
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFirstFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() != item.getItemId()) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        R.id.menu_dialer:
                            replaceFragment(mFirstFragment);
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_email:
                            replaceFragment(mSecondFragment);
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_map:
                            replaceFragment(mThirdFragment);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: without even trying it is obvious  that it will create new fragment.

Comment: Yes, but only once.

Comment: but why only once on every click it goes to that method where it gets the fragment and again creates new one.

Comment: You are wrong. Fragments are created once and are reused each time the `replaceFragment` is called. You can try it yourself and confirm it.

Comment: the output was the same as the pervious answer's case the link is in bottom of the question.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: This will not work because view state is *only* saved when there is a configuration change or if it has been reclaimed due to low memory. A fragment transaction will not trigger it.

Comment: He's right, even though that instance is being created only once, each time a transaction is made, onCreate method inside fragment will be called, recreating the fragment which is not the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but I resolved it by creating multiple fragment hosts then I added fragments in fragmentHost. And when bottom nav itemSelected I just make the required host fragment visible and other host fragmentsHost to visibility gone.

This method may be wrong but it works perfectly for me.
And we don't have to manually handle the states of fragment only we need to handle backpress of activity.
But this method does not pause the fragments.

And I don't know how to handle the pauses and resumes of fragments so please reply to me.

Maybe This will help you.

This is my fragmentHosts Home Activity:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/homeFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_NavBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/libraryFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_NavBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/myStuffFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_NavBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/moreFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_NavBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_NavBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/app_bottom_nav_menu"
        tools:ignore="BottomAppBar" />
```

Home Activity onCreate:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homeFragmentHost,HomeFragment()).commitNow()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.libraryFragmentHost,LibraryFragment()).commitNow()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myStuffFragmentHost,MyStuffFragment()).commitNow()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.moreFragmentHost,MoreFragment()).commitNow()
    homeFragmentHost.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Bottom nav Item Selected listener

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when(item.itemId){
        R.id.homeFragment -> loadFragmentHost(homeFragmentHost)
        R.id.libraryFragment -> loadFragmentHost(libraryFragmentHost)
        R.id.myStuffFragment -> loadFragmentHost(myStuffFragmentHost)
        R.id.moreFragment -> loadFragmentHost(moreFragmentHost)
        else -> false
    }
```

loadFragmentHost function

```
    private fun loadFragmentHost(view:FragmentContainerView): Boolean {
    val list = arrayListOf(homeFragmentHost,libraryFragmentHost,myStuffFragmentHost,moreFragmentHost)
    list.remove(view)
    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    list.forEach {
        it.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    return true
}
```