# Android - Fragment called by Bottom navigation tabs is reloading every time

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am creating a project which uses bottom navigation.
I am using fragment to make tabs call

```
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, Fragment1.newInstance(),Fragment1.newInstance().TAG)
transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit()

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(object : BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

            if(item.itemId == lastSelectedItemId){
                return true
            }

            var menuTag:String ?= null
            var selectedFragment: Fragment? = null
            lastSelectedItemId = item.itemId

            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.tab1 -> {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment1.newInstance()
                    menuTag = selectedFragment.TAG
                }
                R.id.tab2 -> {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment2.newInstance()
                    menuTag = selectedFragment.TAG
                }
                R.id.tab3 -> {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment3.newInstance()
                    menuTag = selectedFragment.TAG
                }
                R.id.tab4 ->{
                    selectedFragment = Fragment4.newInstance()
                    menuTag = selectedFragment.TAG
                }
            }

            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment,menuTag)
            transaction.addToBackStack(menuTag).commit()
            return true
        }
    })
```

But Fragment always reload
I tired some method

1. replace().addToBackStack(null)
2. replace().addToBackStack(tag)
3. add, hide,show

addToBackStack() - using this, when i clicked android default bottom back button, its messing my layout of fragment. same with return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

I followed many forum related this issue, but in my case nothing is working.

My forth fragment is

```
class Fragment4 : Fragment() {

var listOfMoreMenus = ArrayList<MoreLinksObject>()
var adapter: MoreLinksAdapter?=null
public var TAG: String = "more"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val moreView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false)
    val listView = moreView.findViewById(R.id.moreLinks) as ListView

    listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test1","link1")) 
    listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test2","link2")) 
    listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test3","link3")) 
    listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
    adapter = MoreLinksAdapter(getActivity()!!,listOfMoreMenus)
    listView.adapter = adapter
    return moreView

}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): Fragment4 {
        return Fragment4()
    }
}


inner class MoreLinksAdapter: BaseAdapter {

    var  listOfMoreMenus= ArrayList<MoreLinksObject>()
    var context: Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context, listOfMoreMenus: ArrayList<MoreLinksObject>):super(){
        this.listOfMoreMenus=listOfMoreMenus
        this.context=context

    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return listOfMoreMenus[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return  listOfMoreMenus.size
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val MoreLinkObj =  listOfMoreMenus[position]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.more_menu, null)
        val moreMenuName = myView.findViewById(R.id.moreMenuName) as TextView
        moreMenuName.text =  MoreLinkObj.name!!
        return myView
    }

}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130713/bottomnavigationview-how-to-avoid-recreation-of-fragments-and-reuse-them here is already asked questions with solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're providing a new instance, calling `newInstance()` everytime, of each fragment everytime an option is selected. You have two options here:

**1) Array of fragments**

Keep your fragments in a global array when they're created and just reuse it

**2) Tag**

Add a tag to the fragment and use it to find the same fragment later.

As you're already setting the tags that's the best for you:

```
val FRAGMENT_1_TAG =  "FRAGMENT_1_TAG"
val FRAGMENT_2_TAG =  "FRAGMENT_2_TAG"
val FRAGMENT_3_TAG =  "FRAGMENT_3_TAG"
val FRAGMENT_4_TAG =  "FRAGMENT_4_TAG"

when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.tab1 -> {
                title = "Fragment1"
                selectedFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_1_TAG);
                if (selectedFragment == null) {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment1.newInstance()
                }
                menuTag = FRAGMENT_1_TAG
                }
                R.id.tab2 -> {
                title = "Fragment2"
                selectedFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_2_TAG);
                if (selectedFragment == null) {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment2.newInstance()
                }
                    menuTag = FRAGMENT_2_TAG
                }
                R.id.tab3 -> {
                title = "Fragment3"
                selectedFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_3_TAG);
                if (selectedFragment == null) {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment3.newInstance()
                }
                    menuTag = FRAGMENT_3_TAG
                }
                R.id.tab4 ->{
                title = "Fragment4"
                selectedFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_4_TAG);
                if (selectedFragment == null) {
                    selectedFragment = Fragment4.newInstance()
                }
                    menuTag = FRAGMENT_4_TAG
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

To clear the listview you can simply clear it before adding new content, therefore everytime onCreateView is called your list will be initialized from scratch:

```
listOfMoreMenus.clear()
listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test1","link1")) 
listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test2","link2")) 
listOfMoreMenus.add(MoreLinksObject("test3","link3"))
```

As for changing the title, if your toolbar belongs to the activity you can set the title everytime you change fragments.(see above). If it belongs in the fragment then you need to change it in the onCreateView method so it will be changed everytime the fragment is changed.

Comment: What is fragmentManager in option - 2 ? I am new with app developement

Comment: sorry, it should supportFragmentManager in your case

Comment: Yes, but one thing when i pressed android default bottom back button, Title of toobar does not changes but content replaced by previous fragment. In Fragement4 i am using list view and its increases every time when i go back to that 4th fragment

Comment: Are you still adding to the backstack? I reckon if you remove that it will work. Your list view is increasing in fragment 4 probably because you're readding items in one of the fragment's life cycle methods that gets called every time the fragment is changed (like  oncreateview)

Comment: Mean there is nothing  can do like override fun onBackPressed() {} and clear list view or anything else and set title of toolbar -

Comment: Humm, let me see your fragment 4 code, maybe I can give you a hand :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. just last thing is change title of toolbar (I am using custom toolbar which has title with  val title = findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle) as TextView. when ever i pressed back button.. title should change

Comment: So you should use title.text = "Desired title" :)

Comment: Where, right now when i pressed back button, frame layout changed but not tootlbar title

Comment: Did you stop using the backstack?

Comment: No, i did not stop

Comment: So if you still want to use the backstack you'll need to manage the toolbar change yourself as the backstack will only replace the fragment for you, if you don't want to worry about that disable it :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help you, if you need anything just let me know :)

Comment: Actually, if you pressed backbutton, its killing that app, you need to open app gain from scratch(not using backstack)

Comment: Yeah, if you don't use the backstack there won't be anything in the backstack and the app will simply exit