# New instance of fragment is created everytime a tab is selected in BottomNavigationView with navigation

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView with navigation according to android guidelines, the issue i am facing is new fragment is created everytime I go to another tab. I tried to explore and follow different solutions, but nothing works so far. Is there any work around which anyone has tried to make it work?

Comment: Avoiding Fragment recreation with Bottom Nav View: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130713/bottomnavigationview-how-to-avoid-recreation-of-fragments-and-reuse-them/50939140

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating fragment as singleton by using the below code snippet: -

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment{

    private static YourFragment instance;

    public static YourFragment getInstance(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new YourFragment();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now create object of fragment using by `YourFragment.getInstance();`

It won't create a new object every time.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method.

```
Fragment currentlyActiveFragment = null; 

private void showActiveFragment(Fragment nextFragment){
    currentlyActiveFragment = nextFragment;
    
    if (currentlyActiveFragment!=null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .show(currentlyActiveFragment)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Then keep some references of your fragments:

```java
private FragmentA fragmentA=null; 
private FragmentB fragmentB=null;
// ... ...
```

So whenever you click on your button, you do the following check:

```
btnToOpenFragmentA.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (fragmentA == null) {
        // create this fragment 
        fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.layout.baseFrameLayout, fragmentA, FragmentA.TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
        showActiveFragment(fragmentA);
    }
});
```

So this basically checks: if the fragment already exists in the stack, don't create it, instead bring it to top, else create a new object.